# How to befriend private nested class

Tags: c++, c++17, friend

I thought I could do this:

```
class TestA
{
private:
  class Nested
  {

  };
};

class TestB
{
public:
  friend class TestA;
  friend class TestA::Nested;
};
```

But I get an error:

> Error C2248 'TestA::Nested': cannot access private class declared in class

Is there a way to befriend private nested class? How do I do it?

I encountered this error when trying to compile an MSVC 6 project in MSVC 2017 (C++17). I guess it worked back then.

Comment: @TarickWelling No.  `TestB` does not derive from `TestA`.

Comment: `TestA` would need to declare `TestB` as a `friend`.    `TestB` cannot use `TestA::Nested` unless `TestA` allows that.

Comment: Is `TestA` supposed to be a friend too, or *just* `Nested`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Same way you get access to any other private thing. You need friendship the other way:

```
class TestA
{
  friend class TestB; // <== this
private:
  class Nested
  {

  };
};

class TestB
{
public:
  friend class TestA;
  friend class TestA::Nested; // <== now we're a friend of TestA, so we can access it
};
```

Comment: @Quentin I'm saying that barry has found a `struct`ural way of life `while` maintaining `class`. It is why I aspire to be a `friend`.

Comment: @SombreroChicken And you can't spell _maintaining_ without `int main()`.

Answer (score 9):

This will do it:

```
class TestA {
   friend class TestB;
   private:

   class Nested {};
};

class TestB {
   public:
      friend class TestA::Nested;
};
```

Explanation: It's `TestA` itself that has the responsibility to give access to its internals to others. Imagine any `class` could intrusively use friendship to get access to other classes' internals (from libraries etc.), this would open the door to arbitrarily break encapsulation.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks for giving my answer more self-confidence ;)

Comment: How would *granting* friendship to an inaccessible class break encapsulation?  The more likely issue would seem to be fragility from renaming/removing the private class.

Comment: @DavisHerring Renaming/removing is indeed another issue, good point. What I meant was that if some client code were able to put itself into a `friend` relationship with another class, possibly outside of its own codebase, then this does break encapsulation.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to use the `private` nested class of `TestA` in `TestB`, then you should declare `TestB` as the *`friend`* in `TestA`. e.g.

```
class TestA
{
private:
  class Nested
  {

  };
  friend class TestB; // allow TestB to access the private members of TestA
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out the `friend class TestA::Nested;` line as below:

```cpp
class TestA
{
private:
  class Nested
  {

  };
};

class TestB
{
public:
  friend class TestA;
  // friend class TestA::Nested;
};
```

Since `TestA::Nested` has a similar scope as `TestA`, `TestA::Nested`'s method can access private/protected members of TestB.

Comment: I wonder if the downvoters have actually tested this. This answer is 100% correct https://godbolt.org/z/VypZo2

Comment: @sebrockm - Did you miss the fact it doesn't allow to access `Nested`? It doesn't answer the question correctly. Or do you upvote every piece of code irregardless of its relevance?

Comment: @StoryTeller please help me identify the part of the question that wants to access `Nested`. If my English is not overwhelmingly flawed, the OP wants to give `TestA::Nested` access to private fields of `TestB` (aka make `Nested` a friend of `TestB`). And this answer says "By making `TestA` a friend, `Nested` will automatically be a friend, too." So what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: @sebrockm - Nested is not a friend too, it's using the friendship of `TestA` and the scoping rules. Which may or may not be acceptable. However, it does not answer the question of how to befriend `Nested` itself. The OP seems to want it *despite* the ability to befriend `TestA`. Hence people are within their right to consider this answer not useful to the question. 100% correct or not.

Comment: @StoryTeller whether hair-splitting about some naming (is it called friendship or not), although it does exactly the same, justifies a downvote or not, may be subject of discussion. However, I rather believe that the downvoters just didn't believe this works, without testing it, *or* misinterpreted who should have access to whom (as it just happened to you).

Comment: @sebrockm - Do not put words in my mouth. I called it irrelevant, not incorrect. And do not presume to know how others vote or based on what. Your vote is fine, your comment is not. Good day.